# xslt: merging elements by id with recursion

Tags: xml, xslt

Consider the following 2 files:

file1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <foo>
        <bar1 id="1">
            <el1 id="1.1">Bar1 el1</el1>
            <el2 nil="yes" />
        </bar1>
        <bar2 id="2" nil="yes" />
        <bar3 id="3">
            <el1>Bar3 el1</el1>
            <el2>
                <someValue1>5</someValue1>
            </el2>
        </bar3>
    </foo>
</root>
```

file2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<trunk>
    <bar2 id="2">
        <someValue2>11</someValue2>
    </bar2>
    <bar3 id="3">
        <el2>
            <someValue3>8</someValue3>
        </el2>
    </bar3>
</trunk>
```

I would like to merge these two files with the following rules: 
- File2 (trunk) should be added overriding data from File1 (root/foo);
- If elements already exist in File1, only existing data should be replaced, but any child elements should be preserved. The result in this case should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <foo>
        <bar1 id="1">
            <el1 id="1.1">Bar1 el1</el1>
            <el2 nil="yes"/>
        </bar1>
        <bar2 id="2">
            <someValue2>11</someValue2>
        </bar2>
        <bar3 id="3">
            <el1>Bar3 el1</el1>
            <el2>
                <someValue1>5</someValue1>
                <someValue3>8</someValue3>
            </el2>
        </bar3>
    </foo>
</root>
```

I have been able to create an xslt file that comes close but bar3/el2 elements appear twice. Of course I can go 1 level deeper but the nesting of child elements of bar3 (or any other element) should not be limited. This is the xlst I have tried so far:

```
  <xsl:variable name="supplement" select="document('file2.xml')" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="foo//*[@id]" >
     <xsl:variable name="sup-element" select="$supplement//*[@id=current()/@id]"/>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$sup-element">
            <xsl:element name="{name()}" >
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$sup-element/@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="./*|$sup-element/*"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

I have found some examples of merging elements with nesting, but since I have little experience with xslt I could use some help.

Comment: What XSLT version can you use? 1.0 or above?

Comment: The subject says merging elements by id with recursion but the `el2` elements don't have any `id`. So what determines merging or replacement at lower levels, the element name, the id, both? Can there be a `bar1 id="e1"` in one document and `bar2 id="e2"` in the other and they need to be merged based on the same `id` attribute?

Comment: To clarify: the id is only important at the _level_ of the `bar1`, `bar2` etc. elements (i.e. level 3 in file1 and level 2 in file2). The element name can be disregarded here so for instance `bar1 id="e1"` and `bar2 id="e1"` should be merged (but in my case I can be sure that if the id matches in both documents that also the element names will match). I am using xslt 1.0.